# Renombrar un fichero ya abierto

Tags: java, botón, archivo

Hola a quien sea que me ayude tengo el siguiente problema quiero renombrar un archivo ya abierto previamente con x contenido en texto que al pulsar un boton salga un showInputDialog y ahi cambie el nombre del archivo junto a la extencion.

```
// este lo puse solo como referencia espero ayude a mi duda
 public String GuardarArchivo(File archivo, String documento) {
        String mensaje = null;
        try {
            salida = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
            byte[] bytxt = documento.getBytes();
            salida.write(bytxt);
            mensaje = "Archivo Guardado";
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return mensaje;
    }
```

esto es lo que tengo para el cambio de nombre pulsando el boton

````
private void BtnRenombrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String renombre = "";
        String documento = txtarea.getText();
        renombre=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"renombre su archivo con la extencion txt");
        File oldfile = new File(archivo.getAbsolutePath());
        archivo =seleccionar.getSelectedFile();
        File newfile = new File(renombre);// aqui no se como hacerlo para que haga el cambio
        if (oldfile.renameTo(newfile)) {
            System.out.println("archivo renombrado");
        } else {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
}```
````

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? En todo caso dependerá del SO, algunos (Windows) simplemente no dejan renombrar un fichero abierto, así que hay que cerrarlo y volverlo a abrir o hacer alguna cosa rara.